# how to avoid clickable of certain nodes of tree layout in d3 js

Tags: d3.js

I have a tree layout with children and sub-children. This layout supports collapsing. On click of any node, it will collapse and on second click on it it will expand. I want to avoid this effect for certain nodes. How can I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The collapse/expand action is triggered through the `.click` handler. If you want to disable it, have an empty handler for those nodes. The code would look something like this.

```
nodes.on("click", function(d) {
  if(d.condition) {
    // handler for collapsing/expanding
  }
  // if condition is not met, do nothing on click
});
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to accomplish this is to disable pointer events for nodes that you don't want to respond to click handlers.

```
nodes
  // Make sure all nodes' pointer events are reset to 'all'.
  .attr('pointer-events', 'all')
  // Filter the nodes based upon a condition.
  .filter(function(d) { return d.condition; })
  // Set the pointer events for the filtered nodes to 'none'.
  .attr('pointer-events', 'none');
```

This has the added benefit of having nodes that should not respond to clicks also not respond to other mouse events such as mouseover, if that's the behavior you want. If your nodes that shouldn't respond to clicks need to respond to mouseover/mouseout events for instance, go with Lars' solution.